# TFS seems to be stuck in the 'getting sources' step?

Tags: tfs

I finally got the server account working for the build.

Now when I run a skeleton build it is stuck on the 'getting sources' step, the green bar is glowing and all but no other response?

Comment: which version of TFS?  The build structures are different enough between the two (esp. with workspace mappings/cloaking) that it would make a big enough difference in troubleshooting steps

Comment: What happens when it eventually times out?  What does buildlog.txt say?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2005, or 2008 with the  tag set to false, then TFS will try to remove & recreate the build workspace every time.  This can cause problems when, for example, one of the files in the workspace is locked by another process (like cmd.exe - gets me every time).

Answer (score 0):

You could run build from cmd line and check what's happening, you can also change default working directory in build controller to shorter name, because sometimes default directory name length is exceeded.